# Access member of non-virtual base class inherited from two different classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, scope, multiple-inheritance

In a multiple derived class whose base classes inherit from the same base class and both the base classes define a member with same name as one in their base class, how to access the member via different path?

The title is quite long, here's an illustration.

```
struct A{int i;};
struct B1:A{int i;};//non virtual
struct B2:A{int i;};//non vitual
struct C:B1,B2{};
```

Now how to access the `i` in `A` in `B1` or `i` in `A` in `B1` in a `C` object?

To be clearer, `c.i` is of course ambiguous, where `c` is a `C`. But `c.A::i` is also ambiguous, there are two viable paths:

```
C -> B1 -> A
C -> B2 -> A
```

How do I specify one to use?

Comment: `c.B2::A::i` seems to work with MSVC, but not with GCC or Clang.

Comment: `c.B1::i` and `c.B2::i` or do I miss something?

Comment: @SergeyA There is member named `i` in `B1` and `B2`.

Comment: @user yes. But you still can access them independently. Why exactly my suggestion doesn't work for you?

Comment: @SergeyA You are accessing member `i` in `B1` or `B2`, while I want to access `i` in `A`.

Comment: @user oh my, I am stupid to not see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static_cast` is a verbose, but explicit approach:

```
C c;
static_cast<B1&>(c).i;
static_cast<B2&>(c).i;
static_cast<A&>(static_cast<B1&>(c)).i;
static_cast<A&>(static_cast<B2&>(c)).i;
```

Comment: Alternatively, `static_cast<B1&>(c).A::i`.

Comment: @user `static_cast` doesn't usually have runtime cost. You can verify by trying it out with a compiler.

Comment: @user in this particular context, there's no additional generated code.